# Python - Transfer string without escape or with encoding?

Tags: python, encoding

Python 2.7.10 Shell

```
>>> a = "\\xe4\\xbb\\xa5\\xe5\\x8f\\xa5\\xe3\\x81\\x82\\xe3\\x81\\xae"
>>> b = "\xe4\xbb\xa5\xe5\x8f\xa5\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\xae"

>>> print a
\xe4\xbb\xa5\xe5\x8f\xa5\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\xae

>>> print b
以句あの

>>>
```

Var `a` is exactly same as var `b` in our eyes, but they are different in bytes/bits level. Now I want the print-result of `a` is same as the print-result of `b`, any solutions?

In other word, how to transfer `a` to `b` ?

Thanks in advance :)

---

Thanks to @Bishakh Ghosh 's answer, help me a lot.

In the specific version of my Python:

```
>>> print a.decode('string-escape')
以句あの
>>> print a.decode('unicode_escape')
ä»¥å¥ãã

>>> b = a.decode('string-escape')
```

Thanks ~~~ ((●'◡'●)ﾉ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
b = a.decode('string-escape')
```

Or if you want to print `a` directly:

```
print(a.decode('string-escape'))
```

Comment: Getting this: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x8f' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: For me it works fine. Are you using some different string to test? Or different python version?

Comment: I'm using the same strings with python 2.

Comment: I think you are trying to do `b.decode('unicode-escape')` which will not work. You need to do `a.decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: No, I did exactly what you posted. It's probably to do with the version.

Comment: `print(a.decode('string-escape'))`  will print the correct results .  `print(a.decode('unicode-escape'))` results mess .  Thanks a lot,  you saved my a day life .